# Add fedora repositories in Qubes

Tags: fedora, qubes

How to add fedora packages in Qubes. I tried without success:

```
$ sudo qubes-dom0-update qubes-template-fedora-30
Using sys-whonix as UpdateVM to download update for Dom0; this may tike some time...
No Match for argument qubes-template-fedora-30
Nothing to download
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess template repo isn't enabled in dom0 (somehow).
Try these ......

1. sudo qubes-dom0-update --enablerepo=qubes-dom0-templates-itl
2. sudo qubes-dom0-update --enablerepo=qubes-dom0-templates-itl --action=search qubes-template-fedora-30

Now you will see the fedora-30 template package.
Install that package by accurate name like....

1. sudo qubes-dom0-update --enablerepo=qubes-dom0-templates-itl qubes-template-fedora-30